# java and php get request

Tags: java, php, http, get

i want to make an application which is based on a php page, sending to it parameters to obtain data from the remote db through the php page.

I will use jsons, but my question is:

assumed i use this code to send request:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.francescorizzi.altervista.org/Main.php?Request=Login&UserName=mario&Password=lol");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;

while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Should i recreate the url object, conn, and rd at each new request? or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Please note: I'm new to http handling through java.

Comment: do you want to build the app with java or with php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: @monterico The app is in java, the data are retrieved through php.

Comment: @bub Thanks for your answer, i noticed that doing multiple url.openConnection() is fine, so it's not a heavy process.

But what about the input stream? should i reinitialize it after each openConnection() call?

Comment: @Francesco Rizzi : yes, you have to create a new reader for each request, since you get a new inputstream each time.

Comment: when you say "I will use jsons", do you mean that the result is in JSON format?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto yes, i mean that.

Comment: @Berger unfortunately, doing all the stuff you suggested makes my session to get closed... I need to store session data for the whole process, which encloses the multiple GET requests.

is there a way to do so? thanks

Answer (score 1):

since it is an http request and you retrieving data from that particular url, there is a need to recreate the object because the site may get updated later. so creating new object again will dispose the previous object reference and also close connection after retrieving data.